# Can Salesforce update the MCCordovaPlugin to support Geofencing?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush-android

from https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/location/geolocation.html

```
MarketingCloudSdk.init(this, with(MarketingCloudConfig.builder()) {
  // Other configuration values
  **setGeofencingEnabled(true)** // Enable Geofence messaging, default = false
  build()
}) {
  // TODO Handle initialization status
}
```

I can fork the repo. Would it be as simple as adding the **`setGeofencingEnabled(true)`** call?

Answer (score 5):

In your fork of the plugin you would need to follow all of the steps from https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/location/geolocation.html not just adding the feature enablement to the initialization call.

1. Add the play services location dependency to your build
2. Add the location permissions to your manifest file
3. Enable the feature during initialization
4. Request the runtime location permission from your user
5. Enable the feature at runtime once the permission has been granted.

There would be a similar set of steps required for the iOS platform.  You can find that information here: https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/location/geolocation-overview.html